# How to handle a moody ftp server?

Tags: c#, ftp

I want to upload data to an ftp server using a small application. I use this function:

```
public void upload(string remoteFile, string localFile)
{
    try
    {
       ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(host + "/" + remoteFile);
        ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

        ftpRequest.UseBinary = true;
        ftpRequest.UsePassive = true;
        ftpRequest.KeepAlive = true;

        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream();

        FileStream localFileStream = new FileStream(localFile, FileMode.Open);

        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);

        try
        {
            while (bytesSent != 0)
            {
                ftpStream.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesSent);
                bytesSent = localFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }

        localFileStream.Close();
        ftpStream.Close();
        ftpRequest = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
    return;
}
```

The Server however does not respond to my STOR request, or any other request in regard to the files on the server (LIST, etc.):
[image]

However, a programm like FileZilla can connect to the server and get a proper response.
[image]

Once FileZilla established a connection to the server, my application also can communicate with the server and upload files.

What is happening here? How can I handle this?

Comment: Show us equivalent logs (not `LIST` in one and `STOR` in the other). Also, I assume you get some exception? What is it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl edited. A timeout exception occours at  ftpStream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream(); The files are not too large or anything. I even set the timeout to infinity once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the ftp server itself had a bug...

A colleague found out that there is some problem/mix-up with the ports.
The infuriating bug is, that the server starts responding to the **third** LIST Request. From there on out he responds to all other requests as well. However he does **not** respond to the third STOR request, as I have tried this several times.

So my workaround is to send the LIST request untill I get an answer. Then I continue with my STOR request or any other request that I need.

This will obviously not work for everyone with a 'moody' ftp server. But I guess the bottom line is:

If you absolutley can't find the the bug in your code, make sure the ftp server itself is bug-free.